# What is this time format? "2019-03-31T08:29:00"

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to determine what time format is this string "**2019-03-31T08:29:00**" so I can convert it to datetime object but I can't find the answer to this.

Can somebody help please?

Comment: Tis ISO 8601 format.

Answer (score -1):

The format is a standard one:
[ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)